# css in my JavaScript widget colliding with target page css

Tags: javascript, css

I've written a pretty basic widget for voting, users install it pretty much like the Google analytics code by simply adding a JavaScript code to the bottom of their code.

A problem I have noticed now on some pages that use broad CSS rules is that the widget design gets a bit messed up. In my widget CSS I have specified unique names so that should not be a problem.

However when a target page uses rules like:

```
body {
    font: 16px/26px Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial;
}
```

It effects the look of my widget.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

**Edit**: I've tried cleanslate - https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate 
but this resets the css on the target page as well

Comment: it is overriding the font in your widget i think.

Comment: Yea, and it messed with my design. Im looking for a way to fix it

Comment: if you have your own font in your widget's css that is in body, try to put it in a class ".font-class" and then wrap it around your widget after body. it might work. i am not sure though

Comment: you can also try `!important`

Answer (score 1):

Use Iframe or use inline CSS for your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Put your widget in an iframe, then it won't be affected by anything on the target page.

Comment: Parts of my widget is inside an iframe but some parts i simply cannot put inside an iframe :/ (due to drag an drop, etc)

Comment: @Alosyius: drag and drop? You mean a drop target or dragging your widget and dropping it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` for the css of your widget.

Example:

```
.widget {
    font: 16px Arial !important;
}
```