# Isolate div from host page's css

Tags: css

I'm developing a widget to show content from my site on other sites and I'm trying to figure out how to isolate the div in which the widget lives from any css from the host page. I've include a jQuery plugin to scope the style to the div, and I'm also trying to use the css `all: initial` and `all: unset`.

I'm running into some problems though. When I apply the aforementioned css properties to the div, everything within is rendered as a string of text (including my javascripts).

I've also attempted placing the widget div inside another div and resetting the css of that div, but it has no effect.

```
<style>
    #company-widget {
        all: initial;
    }
    #company-widget * {
        all: unset;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // jQuery Scoped CSS plugin here

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var company = 'taco-corp';
        $.scoped();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/' + company + '/widget.js?callback=?',
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#company-widget').html(data.html);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="company-widget" style="max-width: 900px;"></div>
```

My case is a bit more complex than [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459130/css-in-my-javascript-widget-colliding-with-target-page-css) because of some constraints I must operate within. My widget depends on bootstrap css, so applying !important to everything is not a feasible option. It also needs to be responsive, so using an iframe is not an option. Lastly, it has to be plug-and-play ready. A user needs to simply drop in the code and have it render. In most cases, I will have no control over anything else on the host page.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Similar problem but I can't just just slap `!important` on everything or put it in an iframe like in the other example you linked to.

Comment: are you ok with just using a reset CSS file (customized to your own unique div id, of course)?

Comment: Yes. All the css needed for the widget is defined within the style block of the widget code that's fetched from the server. I tried using [this approach](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/), with some success, but for some reason it's resetting some of the styles I defined within the widget. I'm not sure how or why.

Answer (score 0):

Try scoping your css.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // jQuery Scoped CSS plugin here

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var company = 'taco-corp';
        $.scoped();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/' + company + '/widget.js?callback=?',
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#company-widget').html(data.html);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="company-widget" style="max-width: 900px;">
<style scoped>
    // Add style here. It will only be applied to the parent div
</style>
</div>
```

Also see--> http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/style.html
And also-->http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-style-scoped

Comment: Already did that. The scoped style block is defined within the widget template, which is fetched by the ajax call in the code. My goal in doing that was to reduce the number of http requests and the amount of code the client receives.

Comment: I must be missing what your question is. If you are already scoped why are you worried about isolating the `div`? it should automatically follow your styling, ignoring any css on the host page.

Comment: Scoping doesn't work that way as far as I know. Scoping a `<style>` block merely limits your css to the element containing the block and all its child elements. It doesn't prevent higher level css from affecting the scoped element.

Comment: isn't that exactly what you want though? To limit the CSS to your `div` and all children and not affect any other element in the same page?

Comment: That's only half of what I want. I also need to prevent any css (other than my own) from affecting the widget div. Essentially, my div needs to be like an iframe and that it is disconnected from the rest of the document's css.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that seems to be holding up in a production environment with the widget embedded on a host page.

I then used [cleanslate.css](https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate) to 'sanitize' my widget container. This is done before the AJAX call is made.

I then used the [PM5544/scoped-polyfill](https://github.com/PM5544/scoped-polyfill) plugin to scope my style block to the container.

Conveniently, I was able to call this code inside the widget code that is fetched from the server, instead of after the AJAX call that the client puts in their code, meaning less code for the client to deal with.

I had originally tried scoping my div using this [jQuery-Scoped-CSS Plugin](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin), but it doesn't work very well. Some of the scoped styles leak out and affect the host page. I filed an issue report, but it looks like the author has abandoned the project.

Here is the working code that the client receives:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var company = 'taco-corp';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/' + company + '/widget.js?callback=?',
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#company-widget').html(data.html);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="cleanslate">
    <div id="company-widget" style="max-width: 900px;background:white;"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the scoped style block within the widget code. Note that cleanslate.css must be the first stylesheet loaded and that the scoped-polyfill plugin must be called after the scoped style block.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    // Analytics and other scripts go here
</script>

<style scoped>
    // Load cleanslate.css before any other style sheets
    // Load widget stylesheets
</style>

<script type="application/javascript">
    // Load PM5544/scoped-polyfill plugin 
</script>
```